# How to set color in Emacs display property?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I found Org-mode display superscript by modifying the display property with option `org-script-display`. The superscript/subscript display are toggled by options `org-pretty-entities` and `org-pretty-entities-include-sub-superscripts`.

I want to change superscript/subscript display property foreground color into "yellow".

I need to modify the option `org-script-display`.
But I failed when I set this option value with:

```
  '(((raise -0.3)
     (height 0.7)
     (:foreground "yellow"))
    ((raise 0.3)
     (height 0.7)
     (:foreground "yellow"))
    ((raise -0.5))
    ((raise 0.5))
    )
```

Does anybody knows how to set foreground colour here ?

Comment: For defining a face, look into the defface function. For applying it to superscripts, look into font-lock. If you learn font-locking you'll know how to patch org's font-lock, but (as @lunaryorn mentioned) it won't be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the foreground color with a display spec. Se [Display Property](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Property.html).

You'll need to change the face in order to use a different foreground color, however Org does not define customizable faces for subscripts and superscripts.  You'd have to change the `face` property of these, but to do so you'd first have to find subscripts and superscripts in the text.

TLDR: You quite likely can't change the foreground color of Org mode superscripts and subscripts without writing a non-trivial amount of custom Emacs Lisp code.

Comment: Do you know how to setup a new face ? I want this face is global. Can you tell me where is the manual in Emacs info of add/customizing face ?

Comment: You can't just “add” a new face to Org.  You'd need to patch Org itself to actually use your face for all subscripts and superscripts.